# "No such file or directory" when using Windows Linux Subsystem bash with VS Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using VS Code on Windows 10 with the Windows Linux Subsystem & Ubuntu 18.04.

What I am attempting to do is use VS Code as a python development environment with bash as its terminal and the python3 interpreter installed on the Ubuntu system as its default python executable.

In my User configuration I have:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

set, and under Ubuntu python3 is installed and `python` is an alias to it.

When I attempt to execute a python file I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'c:/Users/R ... /test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My sense is I need to get VS Code passing the path relative to the Linux Subsystem rather than to Windows C:\ to the interpreter. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `/mnt/c/Windows` instead of `C:\Windows`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there does not appear to be official support in Visual Studio Code for Windows, the plugin "Code Runner" with the runInTerminal setting fixes this problem.

It adds a "Run Code" (Alt-Ctrl-N) to the right-click window of an open editor.

If you set the User setting:

"code-runner.runInTerminal": true

And then run the code, it passes the correct filename to the default executable for your terminal environment.

Comment: I needed to leave "code-runner.runInTerminal" unchecked (false) then it worked

Answer (score 2):

Linux is case-sensitive, Windows is not. You have "c:" and "C:" in your script.
Maybe check for any other discrepancies you might have?

Answer (score 2):

WSL is not officially supported by the Python extension yet. See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67) to track the status for adding support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the extension [Remote Development extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack), maybe can fix your problem.
Because it will simulate like the vscode is running in the WSl.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_installation